# Between use two years in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to delete the data between some years, like Table name is `t1`, Columns `id,name date`.

The values like this

```
+--+----+----------+
|id|name|date      |
+--+----+----------+
|1 |Raj |2013-03-01|
+--+----+----------+
|2 |Raja|2014-04-05|
+--+----+----------+
```

Now i want to delete this record using years. I tried like this

```
delete from appsetup.company2 where compno=2 and date_trunc('year',acfrom)
between '2013' and '2015'
```

Its Show Error **invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "2013"**. How to achive this?.

I am using postgresql 9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try entering the date in YYYY-MM-DD format, like this: `'2015-12-31'`

So, instead of this:

```
between '2013' and '2015'
```

Try this:

```
between '2013-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
```

More information on how to enter literal values here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Edit: Sorry, I gave you the MySQL link because you tagged your question "mysql". Here's the equivalent for PostgreSQL:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: sir, change the which date formate?. Column date format ah? that date already have that foramt

Comment: You are using this in your statement: `between '2013' and '2015'` The database doesn't recognize just a year as a date, you have to specify the date down to the day for it to be recognized.

Comment: I've shown you how to do it in the answer, is that not clear?

Comment: It might be easier to extract year from the date with `date_part` and use `between '2013' and '2015'`

Comment: !Igor: You could do that, but it will prevent the use indexes, which will tend to destroy your performance in real-world situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out this must solve your problem

```
delete from appsetup.company2 where date_trunc('day',cast(dt_date as timestamp)) between '2013-03-01' and '2014-07-05';
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer: it work fine for me

```
delete from appsetup.company2 where cast(to_char(acfrom,'yyyy') as integer)
between 2013 and 2015
```